# Using USB 3 controller with Linux 2.6.x

Tags: linux, usb

I have a laptop that has an USB controller and an SD card which I believe connected to USB3.

I need to do some development on a Linux version 2.6 which doesn't support USB3.

Can I use USB 3 controller in USB 2 mode? I am not interested in supporting USB 3 on my linux, just be able to read/write to my SD card (or any Flash drive) using my Linux system.

I am using Linux in a virtual environment.

Comment: Current version of the Linux kernel is 3.8, 2.6.x is _long_ gone... unless you are using the 2.6.32 or 2.6.34 longterm branch. But newfangled stuff such as USB 3 is unlikely to show up there. What exactly do you want to develop on/in an obsolete kernel version, and why?